# show how 42.25 would be stored as a floating point number with an 8-bit mantissa and a 4-bit exponent.

Tags: computer-science

So I know that in binary:

42: 00101000

0.25: 01

I then put combine the numbers so it would be:
00101000.01

Once I get this point I'm not sure how to show the mantissa as an 8-bit and the exponent as a 4 bit?

Thank you

EDIT: I think I've worked it out, would the final answer be 0.01010000111?

Comment: I don't believe that when numbers are stored in binary there are decimal points. Rather, a certain set of numbers is reserved for the mantissa, a certain set for the exponent, a certain part for the fraction and the rest for the number itself.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The mantissa is: 169 = 10101001, the exponent is:-2= 1110
Hope this helps.